# Cannot connect to VNC using VNC viewer, KVM working (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, tightvnc, vncviewer

I brought a VPS today, loaded up xubuntu-desktop + tightvncviewer. set up everything, same as I did on a previous host (that worked fine). I can connect through the KVM on the new hosts website as well as I have disabled all firewalls for testing. I cannot however connect through VNC viewer. Keeps giving me "unable to connect to socket: Connection timed out (10060)". Worked fine with the same setup on an old provider. Also port 5901 is open as checked. I'm fairly new to Linux just starting it this week.